# What does 'Getting the bits' mean?

Tags: meaning

As a heading in this article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/install/

I know the article means, but I cant understand the meaning of this words, maybe is a idioms or slang.

Comment: Hey guys @ColleenV , I know the article means, but I cant understand the meaning of this words, maybe is a idioms or slang.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to add more detail (see the [Please, everyone… details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/465/) post) we may be able to take it off hold. At a minimum, you should include the relevant context so that people don't have to go to another link to understand your question. You should also include what you did to try to answer your question before you asked it here. Did you look up "bits" in the dictionary? Why didn't that help?

Comment: Hey, I know what this 'bits' word and total article means. I just don't know 'Gettting the bits' mean. Why I should include the context in this post? They are all in the article. should I paste the article in this post? I cant understand why I should do this。

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a play on words with the computer "bits" definition:

> bit (bĭt)
>
> n. Computers
>
> A binary digit, having either the value 0 or 1, used to store or
>   represent data.